# Pecuilar Form Submission Problem With Hidden Fields

Tags: php, jquery, parsley.js

I have a very long form that is having problems submitting. The user has several options in a dropdown. Depending on their selection certain chunks of HTML are removed from sight using ".hide()". This all works as expected. The problem is the form will NOT submit if these chunks of HTML code are hidden. If I go to the browser tools and delete each of these hidden HTML chunks the form submits perfectly. I have tried to use ".remove()" to hide these HTML chunks but the problem is I am unable to restore it if the user decides to go back and change a form option. I also tried ".detach()" on these HTML chunks but it does not work if the append function is in another place on the page. I thought that maybe I needed to disable the inputs in these corresponding chunks of HTML. However, that does not make a difference. I also tried to condense the entire chunk of HTML block into a single line (horrible wasteful excess and duplication) and load as "innerHTML". However, there are " bracket?php echo ?bracket " elements inside these HTML blocks that do not cooperate in this condensed single line of HTML. Does anybody know how to get the form to submit while there are hidden blocks of HTML code or another way to get this to work? BTW, I am using parsely to validate on the users side.

My second option is to use ".remove()" but figure out how to replace the HTML plus php echo content on click of a refresh button. ".remove()" does work by removing the content that I manually removed. BUT I am unable to replace all the HTML chunks if the user decides to start over by clicking a reset button which erases inputs and shuttles user to beginning of form. If someone knows how to restore all the HTML chunks of code (see below) to starting position on click that would also work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     var $sections = $('.form_section');

     function navigateTo(index) {

       //Mark the current section with the class 'current'
       $sections
         .removeClass('current')
         .eq(index)
         .addClass('current');

       //Show only the navigation buttons that make sense for the current section:
       $('.form_navigation2 .previous').toggle(index > 0);
       var atTheEnd = index >= $sections.length - 1;
       $('.form_navigation1 .submit_button').toggle(!atTheEnd);
       $('.form_navigation2 [type=submit]').toggle(atTheEnd);
     }

     function curIndex() {
       //Return the current index by looking at which section has the class 'current'
       return $sections.index($sections.filter('.current'));
     }


     $('.form_navigation2 .previous').click(function() {
           navigateTo(curIndex() - 1);
           $('#the_form').reset;

           $('.form_navigation1 .submit_button').click(function() {
             $('#the_form').parsley().whenValidate({
               group: 'block-' + curIndex()
             }).done(function() {
               navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
             });

             //If I remove these hidden chunks of HTML in the browser tools the form submits fine.
             //I have tried .remove(), but unable to restore.
             //I have tried .detach(), also unable to restore.
             //Hide/show works but form does not submit.        
             if ($('.part1').val() == 'option1') {
               $('.group2,.group3,.group5').hide();
               $('#input2,#input3,#input5').prop("disabled", true);
             }
             if ($('.part2').val() == 'option2') {
               $('.group1,.group2,.group5').hide();
               $('#input1,#input2,#input5').prop("disabled", true);
             }

             //Prepare sections by setting the `data-parsley-group` attribute to 'block-0', 'block-1', etc.
             $sections.each(function(index, section) {
               $(section).find(':input').attr('data-parsley-group', 'block-' + index);
             });
             navigateTo(0); //Start at the beginning
           });
       });
     $(document).ready(function() {

 var $sections = $('.form_section');

 function navigateTo(index) {

   //Mark the current section with the class 'current'
   $sections
     .removeClass('current')
     .eq(index)
     .addClass('current');

   //Show only the navigation buttons that make sense for the current section:
   $('.form_navigation2 .previous').toggle(index > 0);
   var atTheEnd = index >= $sections.length - 1;
   $('.form_navigation1 .submit_button').toggle(!atTheEnd);
   $('.form_navigation2 [type=submit]').toggle(atTheEnd);
 }

 function curIndex() {
   //Return the current index by looking at which section has the class 'current'
   return $sections.index($sections.filter('.current'));
 }


 $('.form_navigation2 .previous').click(function() {
       navigateTo(curIndex() - 1);
       $('#the_form').reset;

       $('.form_navigation1 .submit_button').click(function() {
         $('#the_form').parsley().whenValidate({
           group: 'block-' + curIndex()
         }).done(function() {
           navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
         });

         //If I remove these hidden chunks of HTML in the browser tools the form submits fine.
         //I have tried .remove(), but unable to restore.
         //I have tried .detach(), also unable to restore.
         //Hide/show works but form does not submit.        
         if ($('.part1').val() == 'option1') {
           $('.group2,.group3,.group5').hide();
           $('#input2,#input3,#input5').prop("disabled", true);
         }
         if ($('.part2').val() == 'option2') {
           $('.group1,.group2,.group5').hide();
           $('#input1,#input2,#input5').prop("disabled", true);
         }

         //Prepare sections by setting the `data-parsley-group` attribute to 'block-0', 'block-1', etc.
         $sections.each(function(index, section) {
           $(section).find(':input').attr('data-parsley-group', 'block-' + index);
         });
         navigateTo(0); //Start at the beginning
       });
     });
   });
 });

  //HTML Chunks look like this
  <div class="group2">
    <label for"calendarPicker_2A">selection 1</label>
    <div id="error_field_2A">
    </div>
    <p><input type="text" id="calendarPicker_2A" class="calendarsPicker cpDate" name="date2" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('date2'));?>" maxlength="10" required="" data-parsley-required-message="required" data-parsley-pattern="^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$" data-parsley-pattern-message="invalid format" data-parsley-errors-container="#error_field_2A" data-parsley-trigger="keyup"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: You say the form doesnt submit, are there any errors present in the console when this occurs?

Comment: Also, after properly formatting your code above, it appears you are missing some closing parens and brackets at the bottom.

Comment: Also, are you submitting this form via ajax, or via a standard submit (that refreshes the page)?  If ajax, please show that code. Can you please show the rendered form html?

Comment: @WesleySmith Thanks for the reply. This is a regular submission (No AJAX). I tried to clean the form up for SO since most here get angry when there is too much code so please forgive the missing brackets. There is no error. My button just does not do anything following the click. It does work when I clear the hidden HTML code from the browser before the click. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Gotcha, in that case, I think we'll need to see the rendered html for the form in order to better help.

Comment: @WesleySmith ok, I put in a typical chunk of HTML code.

Comment: We're probably going to need to see the full rendered html form, including all the sections you're manipulating and any buttons. This is not a problem that should occur when hiding elements. This leads me to believe that there's some sort of issue with the html itself but we'll need to examine it to know.

Answer (score 0):

You want to exclude `:hidden` fields: `data-parsley-excluded="input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden"`

Comment: Hello @Marc-André Lafortune, Thanks for the reply and help. My script is dynamic. I need to hide portions of HTML (not just inputs) according to a selection that the user makes. It is not hidden all the time. Then the same hidden HTML sections need to be reloaded (shown) if the user goes back to the beginning of the form (reset on click). Do you have a working method to remove large chunks of HTML (including php echoes and inputs) and put them all back on click while not hindering form submission? Thanks